# Memory spike for 30K RPM with 100KB payload each

Tags: java, memory, httpclient, heap-memory, vert.x

While testing with 30K RPM with 100 KB payload size on vert.x httpclient. I am noticing a spike in memory and it goes up until the system crashes, no GC collection in between.

```
httpClient
                .request(requestOpts)
                .onSuccess(
                    request -> {
                        request.send(payload);
                    }
                );
```

While running the same for 2 minutes Average response time was - 71.26 and average throughput was 499.26. But running the same over 3 minutes the system crashes.

NOTE: requests payload is converted into String (Base 64)and then bytes. Since direct conversion was not allowed on Buffer.

Comment: Needs more info. How much memory is assigned to the jvm? How much memory is it spiking to? What buffer are you using

Comment: 8 GB is assigned to JVM, The memory is spiking to 7 GB by when 120000 (in 4 mns) requests are made. Vertx buffer is used

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved. I feel silly to answer this.

The issue was because miss configuration of threadpool.
After changing **keepAlive** to true, it worked. Along with some minor changes on the

> maxPoolSize, keelAliveTimeout, idleTimeout

it worked perfectly fine.